# Cannot get routes in AngularJS to work at all

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I started from scratch and rebuilt it as follows. Freshly downloaded angularJS (1.5.8) and I've simply deposited both angular.js and angular-route.js in the library folder. Set up like this: https://gyazo.com/311679bf07249109671d621bc89d2d52

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>TITLE</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" charset="utf-8">
   </head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">

<div class="header">
  <a href="index.html"><h1>Alice Birt Photography</h1></a>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/photo">My Photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/blog">My Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>

<div class="footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- JS-Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/blog', {
      controller: 'BlogController',
      templateUrl: 'page/blog.html'
    })
    .when('/photo', {
      controller: 'PhotoController',
      templateUrl: 'page/photography.html'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      controller: 'AboutmeController',
      templateUrl: 'page/aboutme.html'
    })
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
  $scope.$route = $route;
  $scope.$location = $location;
  $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
})

app.controller('BlogController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.name = 'BlogController';
  $scope.params = $routeParams;
})

app.controller('PhotoController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.name = 'PhotoController';
  $scope.params = $routeParams;
})

app.controller('AboutmeController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.name = 'AboutmeController';
  $scope.params = $routeParams;
})
```

Comment: I think it come,perhaps from the var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);. Why you don't suppress it and  chain the config to it like angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']).config(); . Same for you controller don't use app but angular.module("myApp").controller().

Comment: Are you sure the version of router and the version of angular you're using are compatible? I know that ui-router is preferred for the newer versions

Comment: I struggled with finding angular.js versions in the first place. Can you direct me to where I can very simply find a copy of angular.js and angular-route.js that work with each other?

Comment: Tried all the suggestions so far, no luck.

Comment: Did you try making your links 'blog' instead of '#/blog'?

Comment: that  .otherwise(
      redirectTo: '/blog'
    ); should be .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/blog'
    });

Comment: your code seems to be working as-is, maybe check the version of angular and routes that you are including? http://run.plnkr.co/OFgoniQ4EZp5CnWn/#/blog

Comment: I can also get the code to work on plnkr too... it just doesn't run from my computer. So weird

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you are getting, you need to give more details about it. Though you can try,

```
$routerProvider.otherwise(redirectTo: '/blog');
```

It automatically redirects to blog when no other route is loaded. and also I couldn't find **ng-app** directive in your html part, you should look into that.